# How do i configurate bootstrap for xpages?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I want to ask you about the configuration to the bootstrap4 xpages,i installed it in the domino server then in the domino designer,when i go to the Aapplication>Properties>XPages>xspProperties>Page generation i select the libraray bootstrap and extlib but when i return to the tab general to choose the theme bootstrap i didn't have this choice! i will illustrate you the problem withe these print screen:

[image: the first print screen]

[image: The second print screen]

Comment: What version of Domino, Domino designer and the Exlib are you using?

Answer (score 4):

This is easiest if the server and Domino Designer are version 9.0.1. Then you can just use the latest Extension Library, which includes everything from Bootstrap4XPages except Select2 component (I believe this was because of licensing issues). Installing the "-designer" package from that will hook into an extension point added subsequently which allows extension libraries to contribute options to that list of themes available.

If using an earlier version of Domino, you need to manually type the relevant theme name into that combobox (it allows you to either select from the available options or type in another option).

Answer (score -2):

Thanks Paul,I installed ExtLib now i have the bootstrap in the list default theme but not in the library id, I will illustrate you the problem with these print screens:
[image: The first print screen]
[image: The second print screen]

Comment: You also need to install it in Designer. This is explained here: http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/pages/extension-lib

Comment: This answer should be a comment. And check the Stackoverflow markdown guides to learn how to embed images

Comment: Originally you were using the bootstrap4xpages extension, so it was showing as a selectable library.

The latest version of the extension library, which is what it looks like you've installed via Pauls instruction has bootstrap built it, so just select the latest ext lib from the page generation tab to be able to use bootstrap components.

Make sure you accept Pauls answer, and another question I've seen of yours recently that Stephan Wissel answered. People go out of their way to help and should receive the recognition for doing so. I'd also suggest reading some Stack Overflow guidelines.